# Rotation snapping from left to right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm creating a sort of first person space invaders game. I've created a spaceship that can move left and right.

The spaceship tilts depending if you pressed left or right, and I used code from the Unity space shooter tutorial:

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0f, 0f) * speed;

        rigidbody.position = new Vector3(
            Mathf.Clamp(rigidbody.position.x, xMin, xMax), 
            0.0f, 
            Mathf.Clamp(rigidbody.position.z, zMin, zMax)
        );

        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }
```

**The problem is** if I am holding the right key, and instantly press the left key, the ship sort of snaps to the other direction. If I press the right key and let go, the ship will smoothly rotate back towards the centre. If I press the left key straight after pressing the right key, it snaps to the opposite way of tilt with no smooth transition.

**I guess** this is because the arrow keys from `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` return either 1 or -1 from input (1 being right, -1 being left) which means that if I press the right key and then the left key straight away, the entire rotation is multipled by -1, causing the snapping effect.

**Is there a way** to smoothly rotate from one side to the other using the arrow keys without causing the tilt to snap?

Comment: it's incredibly wrong to use Quaternions in any way for this, Tom.  If it is a rigidbody, you should simply be applying force or perhaps torque.  To add toruqe you use "AddTorque" (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html).  To add force you use "AddForce" (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Comment: that happens because you are using your input directly to the velocity and as you said it will be 1 or -1 multiplied on movement. Try to alter the rotation instead and increment the speed multipled by the moveHorizontal(1 or -1).

`rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rigidbody.rotation.x + speed * moveHorizontal);`

Comment: @JoeBlow whilst I agree that it is probably wrong (I've taken the code from Unity's tutorials :P) do you perhaps know **why** it's wrong? Just so I know :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Rigidbody class has functions to help you do this safely & smoothly. Check out MovePosition https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html and MoveRotation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html

e.g:

```
rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, 0f) * Time.deltaTime);
```